# Automatic height for tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, tableview

I'm asking for you help to create a tableview with an automatic height

My goal is to create a tableView with some datas (like strings).
But in my case, I can have 4, 7 or 22 strings. So, My goal is to list all the strings, without scrolling inside this TableView but in all the main scroll view

I know how to get automatic row cells height, but It seems that I have to set the height or the bottom constraint to my tableview and it is not my goal.

If you know CCS, the goal is to have a render like "height: auto;". That's it.

Hope to read you with some good news for me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set an initial height constraint in the storyboard and connect an outlet to it. After you get the tableviews data and call `self.tableView.reloadData()` try:

`self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height`

Answer (score 0):

For that wrap tableview inside `UIScrollView`, Then set height of tableview and take outlet of tableview height,

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightOfTable: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

After that we need to observe the height of tableview every time when it changed, For that add below methods in Your `UIViewController`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "contentSize" {
        heightOfTable.constant = min(tableView.contentSize.height, UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had the auto resize of the content but my Scroll View doesn't work. I put a uiview under my tableView with fixed height and my table view have been resized (smaller).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UITableView.automaticDimension in heightForRow event. Also you have to set estimatedRowHeight in viewDidLoad.

Before that you must design your tableview cell without giving any height constraint on label. (I think that you are using label.), also you must give the label lineCount 0.

When you did all of this, it must be done. If you want you can share your code and i can help you then.